# Clear screen in Mitmproxy Linux

Tags: linux, macos, mitmproxy

I'm using Mitmproxy over multiple platforms (linux and os x), and while on os x the combination shift+c clears the console log, on linux it opens the "Export to clipboard" option, as follows:
[image]

Is there a way to clear the mitmproxy logs in linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The shortcuts are shared over all platforms. Are you perhaps using different mitmproxy versions? "clear flow list" has moved to `z`.